# Why is my super simple function on Python wrong?

Tags: python, function

Write a function `check_prime()` that takes an integer and returns `True` if the number is prime, and `False` otherwise.

```
def check_prime(yo):
  yo = int(input)
  if yo % 1 != 0 and yo % yo !=0:
      return("False")
    
  else:
      return("True")
```

Comment: `yo % 1` and `yo % yo` are both always 0.

Comment: Python has a boolean datatype. You don't need strings like "False", you can use False or True directly.

Comment: `yo = int(input)` is wrong, both because you didn't invoke the `input` function, and because you're overwriting the input parameter.

Comment: There are likely a whole bunch of issues going on here. You're probably not supposed to be taking user input, if you're also taking an argument to the function. As interjay said, your conditions don't make any sense, and don't test for primeness in any meaningful way. Lastly, the strings `"True"` and `"False"` are not the same thing as the `bool` values `True` and `False`.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic for prime number is wrong. You can refer to this article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number.

For Python code refer: https://www.javatpoint.com/python-check-prime-number

Also, your syntax for input is wrong. It should be `int(input())`

Answer (score 0):

Note that 1 is *not* a prime number... Try this function to check for prime number:

```
def check_prime(x):
    if x >= 2:
        for y in range(2,x):
            if not (x % y):
                return False
    else:
        return False
    return True

check_prime(int(input('Enter number to check: ')))
```

Output:

```
Enter number to check:  31
True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def check_prime(x):
    if x >= 2:
        for y in range(2,x):
            if not ( x % y ):
                return False
    else:
        return False
    return True
    
print(13,check_prime(13))
print(12,check_prime(12))
print(3,check_prime(3))
print(1,check_prime(1))
print(2,check_prime(2))
print(31,check_prime(31))
print(8,check_prime(8))
```

Output:

```
13 True
12 False
3 True
1 False
2 True
31 True
8 False
```